# Why are my VBA ListBox values not being displayed?

Tags: excel, vba, properties, listbox

I'm working with a VBA Invoice Generator. When searching for a name from the master spreadsheet I get the entries displayed to me in a ListBox. I want to select one of the results from the box but when I choose one, I don't get the entry I've selected, instead I get an entry from the Master spreadsheet - which is obviously a different record.

The result I receive depends on the position of the name in the listbox relative to the spreadsheet; if I choose the first name in the box I get the first entry from the Master spreadsheet, if I choose the second in the box I get the second from the Master etc.

The affected code is below:

```vb
Private Sub btSelect_Click()
    Dim X As Long

    'this is to select the record for editing
    EditNum = Me.LbCustomer.ListIndex
    If EditNum = -1 Then
        MsgBox "nothing has been selected"
    Else
        EditNum = EditNum + 1
    'this is because the list index starts at 0 and you want to ensure you skip the header

    'this next bit copies the values from the listbox to the form
    FmInputMaster.tbCustName = shMaster.Range("A" & EditNum)
    FmInputMaster.tbCompName = shMaster.Range("B" & EditNum)
    FmInputMaster.tbAddr1 = shMaster.Range("C" & EditNum)
    FmInputMaster.tbAddr2 = shMaster.Range("D" & EditNum)
    FmInputMaster.tbAddr3 = shMaster.Range("E" & EditNum)
    FmInputMaster.tbUID = shMaster.Range("F" & EditNum)
    FmInputMaster.tbVAT = shMaster.Range("G" & EditNum)
    FmInputMaster.tbEmail = shMaster.Range("H" & EditNum)

    'then unload the form
    Unload Me
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Are you saying that when you have filled out the userform and click the button your second userform isn't updating?  How did you initalize the userform?  vbmodeless?  Would probably need more info about the userform itself.

Comment: The UserForm is instantiated from a button click inside the excel document, from there another form appears you can use to search the database with User's Name ('Paul' for instance) or Company, relevant details are then listed in the listbox LbCustomers.

Answer (score 0):

To set the value of a TextBox in VBA Forms you must set the value to the ***Text***-Property of the TextBox-Element

like this:

```
FmInputMaster.tbCustName.Text = shMaster.Range("A" & EditNum)
```

change it also for the other **TextBox** elements